# How do you target the disabled state of a submit button?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have looked all over and can't figure this out: how do you target the disabled state submit button in css?

For example: How would I target and style this button:

```
<input value="Validate" disabled="disabled" type="submit"/>
```

Comment: "**target the disabled state submit button**". Can you be more specific?

Comment: I guess he wants to know how to CSS a greyed out button.

Comment: Yeah, I just updated above with an example button

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use:

```
    input[disabled=disabled][type=submit] {
        background:green;
    }
```

Works on Firefox and is **reportedly** good on all but IE6.  But I haven't personally tested this kind of combo selector.

PS:  A more robust, cross-browser method, using jQuery...

```
$("input[disabled=disabled][type=submit]").css
({
    'background':   'yellow',
    'color':        'blue'
});
```

Comment: please note @Veger answer whith a more modern approach using CSS3 :disabled pseudo class

Answer (score 28):

CSS3 adds the [:disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/) pseudoclass, which exactly does what you want.

```
input:disabled {
 /*Disabled styles for input elements here*/
}
```

As [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled) shows all major browsers (except IE8) support this tag, so it seems unusable yet (unless you do not need IE support)

Comment: If you have a boss or client that doesn't require IE support, please call me!  ;-)   I needed weeks and reams of stats just to be allowed to drop IE6 and IE7.

Comment: Hehe... Well you *did* manage to drop IE6 and IE7, saves lots of trouble already!

Answer (score 5):

```
input[disabled='disabled'][type='submit']
{
...
}
```

doesn't work in IE 6 but should in all other browsers. [Reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attributeAdvanced.html)

There is also the [`:disabled` pseudo-class](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/enabled.html) but that's not supported in IE at all.

Styling disabled elements is difficult, as they sometimes have properties that can't be overridden. This article shows what stylings apply in which browsers: [Styling disabled form controls with CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/disabled/)

Comment: Wait, won't this style all disabled elements? Is there a way to specifically target disabled buttons?_

Comment: @Thomas yup, it will. It should be possible to combine this with `[type='submit']` but I don't know how to be honest. A class would work like this: `input.classname[disabled....`

Comment: @Thomas try `[type='submit'][disabled='disabled']` no guarantees though

Answer (score 1):

There is no pseudo class defined in CSS for a disabled state.

My guess is to use JQuery to change the CSS class for the disabled buttons.

Code for JQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('input[type=button]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled') == true)
        {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Add a style element 'disabled'.

Comment: There is a pseudo-class in CSS3, but it's not supported by IE.

Comment: +1, as browser support is very patchy, going down a JS route seems a good solution, as long as you know for sure the clientside has javascript enabled.

Comment: Im using Jquery, how would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of for this is by setting the class of the button to disabled and then using "input.disabled" to specify the appropriate CSS. Would that work in the context you are doing this?

Comment: I thought about that, but I am concerned that this might be seen as poor coding by the engineer... I never know what is going to hack those guys off.

Comment: I agree it's not...'nice', but it's quite a simple solution. Never having worked in a professional coding environment, I don't know what they'll expect, though!

Answer (score 0):

For your exact syntax, @Brock Adam or @Pekka's answer should work, but usually, the syntax for  disabled input or button is:

```
<input disabled type="submit"/>
```

With this, you could do the following to target the disabled property:

```
button:[disabled] {}
input:[disabled] {}
```

Also, because it was what I needed in my case, below can help achieve the reverse (targeting only buttons or inputs that aren't disabled):

```
button:not([disabled]) {}
input:not([disabled]) {}
```