# CSS to produce Windows Style button

Tags: css

I was tinkering around with a few websites in attempting to create and mimic a windows themed style buttons. What would the CSS style patterns be to basically mirror the buttons like the ones found in the picture below?

In the picture, there is an inactive state, hover state and a default state button

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, then please show us.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100868/how-do-you-target-the-disabled-state-of-a-submit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of:

border-style

border-width

border-color

border-radius

background: linear-gradient

Read the documentation here:http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp
For both CSS and CSS3

Answer (score 0):

For the gradient, use this online tool to generate the CSS for you: [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Then you need to apply CSS `border` attribute.

Then you can use the CSS `:hover` selector to change it's looks upon the button element is hovered.

I hope this will give you a start. So play with these things first and let us know the results. We will then give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your default state:

```
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Hover state:

```
button:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Disabled state:

```
button[disabled=disabled] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

These styles are incomplete, but the selectors are the important thing.

The rounded corner effect is generated by adding `border-radius: 3px;` to the `button` css.

To get the gradients, you'll want to use a `background` with a `linear-gradient`; I recommend a tool like www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator to generate the styles for you.